why i am getting null as return message after an api call?

here is the main activity code

here i am getting null as output in a textbook i placed just for checking
i want to know that the api is working correctly  but i am getting this as output
i have also attached the activity.main.xml code below this code
package com.example.trainman

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.TextView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://pnr-status-indian-railway.p.rapidapi.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    
    
        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData(query = "6902637622")
    
        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<myData?>{
    
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<myData?>, response: Response<myData?>) {
            //if the api call is success
                val dataList=response.body()?.data
                val textView=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv2)
                textView.text=dataList.toString()
                Log.d("TAG: onResponse","onResponse: "+ response.body())
    
    
            }
    
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<myData?>, t: Throwable) {
               //if the api call fail
                Log.d("TAG: onFailure","onFailure"+ t.message)
    
            }
        })
    
    }

}

.

**Activity.main xml code ** below this i have attached api interface code.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="59sp"
        android:layout_margin="25sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/search">


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
            android:hint="@string/enter_your_pnr_no"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:paddingStart="55sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:paddingEnd="0sp"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="281dp"
        android:background="#222"
        android:textColor="#F4F0F0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_txt"
        android:textSize="27sp">

    </TextView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="196dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="350dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbg"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:text="@string/pnr_search"
        android:textSize="25sp" />


</LinearLayout>


Api interface part for security reasons i have removed api key
package com.example.trainman

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface ApiInterface {

    @Headers("X-RapidAPI-Key:47f*************************************0",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host:pnr-status-indian-railway.p.rapidapi.com")
    @GET("PNRnumber")
    fun getData(@Query("PNR") query:String) : Call<myData>

}

